# Enum value not comparing to enum in switch

Tags: java, enums

I have a Enum with some names in it in the Constants class:

```
static final enum NAMES {
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five
}
```

I tried to go through them with:

```
 for (Constants.NAMES name in Constants.NAMES.values())
```

And then use them in the switch:

```
 switch (index.key) {
     case Constants.NAMES.One:
```

I have also tried to just use One as the case and Enumset for the loop, the only thing that works is using "One" as a string, but that defeats the purpose of an Enum

This is working:

```
    for (Constants.NAMES script : Constants.NAMES.values()) {
        switch (index.key) {
            case Constants.NAMES.ONE.name():
```

Comment: `for (Constants.NAMES name in Constants.NAMES.values())` is not Java syntax; `for (Constants.NAMES variable : Constants.NAMES.values())` is. By the way: `NAMES` is not a conventional name for an enum. `Names` would be better.

Comment: What is the type of `index.key`? Is it a String?

Comment: It should be the Enum (I use the same Enum when adding it) I just switched to Groovy/Java so syntax is still getting used to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your enum as below :

```
enum NAMES {
    ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE
}
```

`static final` are Illegal Modifiers when used along with declaring enums. Also make sure constants are defined using upper case only.

Then use it using :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String myStr = "something";
    switch (NAMES.valueOf(myStr)) {

    case ONE:
        break;

    case TWO:
        break;

    // the rest 

    default:
        break;
    }

}
```

---

Alternately, you can create a static method to fetch the result from the `enum`

```
enum NAMES {
    ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE;

    public static NAMES fetchValue(String constant) {
        NAMES name = null;
        for (NAMES num : EnumSet.allOf(NAMES.class)) {
            if (num.name().equals(constant)) {
                name = NAMES.valueOf(constant);
            }
        }
        return name;
    }
}
```

And call it using :

```
NAMES names = NAMES.fetchValue("ONE");
```

In this approach, even if the constant is not found the code won't break.

Comment: `fetchValue` seems a bit complicated. Suggestion: `fetchValue(String s) { try { return valueOf(s); } catch (Exception e) { return null; } }`.